# Cant get a field of PDF with PDFBox

Tags: java, string, scala, pdf, pdfbox

I have a pdf with a single field "pls" and when I call method of AcroForm getFields, the output is like this: "COSString{pls}", but when i call method getField("pls") it returns null and i cant do anything with the field.

Comment: Probably a longer name, e.g. a.b.c.pls. You can display the PDF file with PDFDebugger and then hover above the field to see the full name. If this doesn't help, please share your PDF and some minimal code. Also don't use getFields, use getFieldTree, see javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project where I was looking for a field through his name `CustomerSignature`. Maybe this example can help you.

```
PDField myField;
for(PDField f : ((List<PDField>) pdfAccroForm.getFields())) {
    if(f.getPartialName()!= null && f.getPartialName().startsWith("CustomerSignature")) {
        myField= f;
    }
}
```

Comment: use getFieldTree, not getFields, see javadoc why